# asignar valores a una variable usando Parallel.Foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net, hilos

Tengo un problema al usar Parallel.ForEach()

```
foreach (var expresion in lstExpresionesCompleta)
            exprFinalCompleta = exprFinalCompleta == null ? expresion : exprFinalCompleta.Or(expresion);
```

En ocasiones obtengo valores concatenados y otros no, no se si tengo un error al usar parallel.ForEach()

Así tenía el Parallel.ForEach

```
Parallel.ForEach(lstExpresionesCompleta, expresion => { exprFinalCompleta = exprFinalCompleta == null ? item : exprFinalCompleta.Or(item); });
```

Al momento de regresarlo a un foreach me obtenía correctamente concatenado todos los valores con el Or.

Gracias

EDIT

```
public async Task<IQueryable<TEntity>> ApplySecurity(IQueryable<TEntity> query)
    {
        var valorXcolumnaXrol = await _serviceSecurity.GetColumnasValores(Entities.TableName);
        var valorColumnaAgrupadaRoles = valorXcolumnaXrol.GroupBy(x => x.RolNombre).Select(x => x.ToList()).ToList();
        List<Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>> lstExpresionesCompleta = new List<Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>>();
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> exprFinalCompleta = null;
        Parallel.ForEach(valorColumnaAgrupadaRoles, valorColumnas =>
        {
            Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> exprCompletaRol = null;
            List<Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>> lstExpresiones = new List<Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>>();
            foreach (var valorColumna in valorColumnas)
            {
                Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> exprCompletaColummna = null;
                if (valorColumna.TablaNombre == null)
                {
                    exprCompletaColummna = x => true;
                    lstExpresiones.Add(exprCompletaColummna);
                    continue;
                }
                var prefix = GetPrefix(typeof(TEntity));
                var columnaNombreCompleto = prefix + valorColumna.ColumnaNombre.Trim();
                Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> exprInicial = null;
                Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> exprFinal = null;
                if (typeof(TEntity).HasProperty(columnaNombreCompleto))
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(valorColumna.ValorFinal))
                    {
                        exprInicial = ExpressionBuilder.BuildPredicate<TEntity>(valorColumna.ValorInicial, OperatorComparer.GreaterThanOrEqual, columnaNombreCompleto);
                        exprFinal = ExpressionBuilder.BuildPredicate<TEntity>(valorColumna.ValorFinal, OperatorComparer.LessThanOrEqual, columnaNombreCompleto);
                        exprCompletaColummna = exprInicial.And(exprFinal);
                        exprCompletaColummna = exprCompletaColummna.Not();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        exprInicial = ExpressionBuilder.BuildPredicate<TEntity>(valorColumna.ValorInicial, OperatorComparer.NotEqual, columnaNombreCompleto);
                        exprCompletaColummna = exprInicial;
                    }
                    lstExpresiones.Add(exprCompletaColummna);
                }
            }
            foreach (var item in lstExpresiones)
            {
                exprCompletaRol = exprCompletaRol == null ? item : exprCompletaRol.And(item);
            }
            lstExpresionesCompleta.Add(exprCompletaRol);
        });
        foreach (var item in lstExpresionesCompleta)
            exprFinalCompleta = exprFinalCompleta == null ? item : exprFinalCompleta.Or(item);
        if (exprFinalCompleta != null)
            query = query.Where(exprFinalCompleta);
        return await Task.Run(() => { return query; });
    }
```

Construyo expresiones y concateno dependiendo del rol ya que ciertos roles no pueden ver información de ciertas áreas y los filtro desde linq, se forman perfecto las expresiones y en la base de datos igual, pero a veces lo trae con un filtro menos, al quitar el Parallel ya me los trae completos ejemplo

| Rol | Columna | Valor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SYSADMIN | NULL | NULL |
| COMPRASCOMP1 | COMPAÑIA | 1 |
| COMPRASCOMP1 | ALMACEN | 1 |
| COMPRASCOMP2 | COMPAÑIA | 2 |
| COMPRASCOMP2 | ALMACEN | 3 |

Entonces voy concatenando los roles y las columnas para crear la expresion en tiempo de ejecucion, deprendiendo del usuario logueado

Comment: Incluye mayor información por favor. Tal como está la pregunta, es muy improbable que cualquier usuario pueda reproducir tu escenario. Te explico: ¿Qué tipo de variables contiene lstExpresionesCompleta? ¿Son strings? ¿son clases? ¿Qué valores de ejemplo deberíamos considerar para ejecutar tu algoritmo? ¿Cuál es la respuesta esperada para cada caso? Para mayor información de cómo preguntar: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: @fredyfx añadi el edit mas codigo, explicaciones y ejemplo

Comment: Ahora ya estamos en la misma página. El problema va por el tema de concurrencia, al ejecutar cosas en paralelo, se necesita trabajar en paralelo, lo que estás haciendo es mezclar cosas, te funciona bien con un ForEach común y silvestre precisamente porque se ejecutan en un thread. Al utilizar Parallel donde hay mayores hilos, se requiere otra forma más "ordenada", prueba con ConcurrentList para `valorColumnaAgrupadaRoles`. Si la complejidad está elevada, considera utilizar una query a nivel de BD donde revises un contador si tiene filas dependiendo del permiso del usuario. Saludos.